# AssetNotFound on rails 7.0 deployed on heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have installed a new rails 7.0 application, it works fine on my localhost but when I am deploying to heroku I am getting the following error.

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Marketing#index
Showing /myapp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #9 raised:
The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

Comment: Does the `config/manifest.js` has this line `//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css`?

Comment: Yes it does have it.